# Convert AsyncTask to RxJava (Android)

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have some code:

```
  class WorkEngineTask extends AsyncTask<Void, RecognitionResult, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    frameReady.acquire();  // waiting for the frame

                    if (!processing) {
                        break;
                    }
                    Camera.Size size = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
                    RecognitionResult result;
                    switch (mAngle) {
                        case 0:
                            result = session.ProcessYUVSnapshot(mData, size.width, size.height, ImageOrientation.Landscape);
                            break;
                        case 180:
                            result = session.ProcessYUVSnapshot(mData, size.width, size.height, ImageOrientation.InvertedLandscape);
                            break;
                        case 270:
                            result = session.ProcessYUVSnapshot(mData, size.width, size.height, ImageOrientation.InvertedPortrait);
                            break;
                        default:
                            result = session.ProcessYUVSnapshot(mData, size.width, size.height, ImageOrientation.Portrait);
                    }
                    publishProgress(result);  // show current result
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(RecognitionResult... res) {
            RecognitionResult result = res[0];
        }
    }
```

I need convert it to rxJava code.
I'm trying to write some code. Here is my code:

```
 public void workEngine() {
        Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<RecognitionResult>) emitter -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    frameReady.acquire();  // waiting for the frame

                    if (!processing) {
                        break;
                    }

                    Camera.Size size = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
                    RecognitionResult result;

                    switch (mAngle) {
                        case 0:
                            result = session.ProcessYUVSnapshot(mData, size.width, size.height, ImageOrientation.Landscape);
                            break;
                        case 180:
                            result = session.ProcessYUVSnapshot(mData, size.width, size.height, ImageOrientation.InvertedLandscape);
                            break;
                        case 270:
                            result = session.ProcessYUVSnapshot(mData, size.width, size.height, ImageOrientation.InvertedPortrait);
                            break;
                        default:
                            result = session.ProcessYUVSnapshot(mData, size.width, size.height, ImageOrientation.Portrait);
                    }
                    emitter.onNext(result);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String message = "Error while processing frame: " + e.toString();
                    Log.d("smartid", message);
                    callback.error(message);
                }
            }

        }).observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<RecognitionResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(RecognitionResult recognitionResult) {
                        draw.showResult(recognitionResult);
                        draw.invalidate();
                        callback.recognized(recognitionResult);
                        frameWaiting.release();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    }
```

But it's not working for me. I am new on Android and I never use async task, and I don't want use it now. I try many times, but nothing help. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you did to process the result in the AsyncTask, you should do in onNext(); that is when emiited result is observed. Then onComplete() will be called once there is nothing to emitt. So clean up stuff should be done there, like the release call. If there is anything like logging stuff you want in case of error, you do that in onError().

```
 @Override
                        public void onNext(RecognitionResult recognitionResult) {
                            //This doesn't match what you did in the AsyncTask above
                            draw.showResult(recognitionResult);
                            draw.invalidate();
                            callback.recognized(recognitionResult);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                             frameWaiting.release();
                        }
```